# Bcrypt ValueError: Invalid salt when using custom salt

Tags: python, hash, bcrypt, salt

I'm working on a project where hashing is required. The problem is that I want to create a custom hash (generated with a program that would add non-english characters and symbols). When testing this with a simple string I get the error `ValueError: Invalid salt`. The code I tried:

```
def test():
    password = b"pass123"
    password2 = input("Enter password: ")
    bpassword2 = password2.encode('utf-8')

    salt = b"test"

    hashed = bcrypt.hashpw(password, salt)
    print(hashed)

    hash2 = bcrypt.hashpw(bpassword2, bcrypt.gensalt())
    print(hash2)


test()
```

This returns the error. I've also tried:

```
def test():
    password = b"pass123"
    password2 = input("Enter password: ")
    bpassword2 = password2.encode('utf-8')

    salt = "test"

    hashed = bcrypt.hashpw(password, salt)
    print(hashed)

    hash2 = bcrypt.hashpw(bpassword2, bcrypt.gensalt())
    print(hash2)


test()
```

However this returns the error `TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing`. I honestly don't know what to do and if this is a really simple fix then I'm sorry .

Comment: Apparently the error come fron the C implementation of ```bcrypt_hashpass``` inside the ```hashpw``` function. Did you tried using ```salt = bcrypt.gensalt()```

Comment: Hi @Jonatrios thx for the reply. I'm trying to use a different alogrithm to generate more secure/complex salts.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the `bcrypt.hashsalt` expects the salt to be of length > 16 characters. here is the source code of the method:

```
def hashpw(password: bytes, salt: bytes) -> bytes:
  """
  Hash the password with the given salt.
  """
  if len(salt) != 16:
    raise ValueError("Invalid salt")

  hashed = _bcrypt.ffi.new("char[]", 60)
  _bcrypt.lib.bcrypt_hashpw(password, salt, hashed)
  return _bcrypt.ffi.buffer(hashed, 60)[:]
```